# separate 'entangled' vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, difference

I have a set of three vectors (stored into a 3xN matrix) which are 'entangled' (e.g. some value in the second row should be in the third row and vice versa). This 'entanglement' is based on looking at the figure in which alpha2 is plotted. To separate the vector I use a difference based approach where I calculate the difference of one value with respect the three next values (e.g. comparing (1,i) with (:,i+1)). Then I take the minimum and store that. The method works to separate two of the three vectors, but not for the last.

I was wondering if you guys can share your ideas with me how to solve this problem (if possible). I have added my coded below.

Thanks in advance!

Problem in figures:
[image: 'Entangled state']
[image: 'Separated state']

```
clear all; close all; clc;
%%
alpha2 = [-23.32    -23.05  -22.24  -20.91  -19.06  -16.70  -13.83  -10.49  -6.70;
    -0.46     -0.33 0.19    2.38    5.44    9.36    14.15   19.80   26.32;
    -1.58     -1.13 0.06    0.70    1.61    2.78    4.23    5.99    8.09];
%%% Original
figure()
hold on
plot(alpha2(1,:))
plot(alpha2(2,:))
plot(alpha2(3,:))

%%% Store start values
store1(1,1) = alpha2(1,1);
store2(1,1) = alpha2(2,1);
store3(1,1) = alpha2(3,1);

for i=1:size(alpha2,2)-1
    for j=1:size(alpha2,1)
        Alpha1(j,i) = abs(store1(1,i)-alpha2(j,i+1));
        Alpha2(j,i) = abs(store2(1,i)-alpha2(j,i+1));
        Alpha3(j,i) = abs(store3(1,i)-alpha2(j,i+1));

        [~, I] = min(Alpha1(:,i));
        store1(1,i+1) = alpha2(I,i+1);

        [~, I] = min(Alpha2(:,i));
        store2(1,i+1) = alpha2(I,i+1);

        [~, I] = min(Alpha3(:,i));
        store3(1,i+1) = alpha2(I,i+1);
    end
end
%%% Plot to see if separation worked
figure()
hold on
plot(store1)
plot(store2)
plot(store3)
```

Comment: I'm sorry for being ignorant, but I am unclear as to your criteria for "entanglement".  How do you **know** when some values in one vector are supposed to go into another vector?  You have not made this clear in your problem statement.

Comment: No, you are not being ignorant at all. Basically, the 'entanglement' is based by looking at the figure.

Comment: I see.  That's very lovely.  So how does looking at the figure tell you how it's entangled?

Comment: I agree it is an odd question and one that possible cannot be solved just by having the matrix alpha2 (hence, I stated if possible). However, if you would plot the figure you would see the curves are not 'smooth', based on that you see that if you would change parts of row 2 and row 3 would give you a smoother curve.

Comment: Ahhhhh.OK. I don't think you mean to say that the data is "entangled".  I think you mean to say that your data has some noise, and you would like to filter or eliminate this noise as best as possible.  Essentially, you want to filter each row so that it becomes "smooth".  Are you allowed to mutate the final result, or can you only use data that is native to the vector?  What I mean to say is that for each element that is possibly "noisy", is the output limited to only selecting one of the points in the data, or can we perhaps combine them in a way? Averaging over a local neighbourhood perhaps?

Comment: Indeed, the word 'entangled' maybe incorrect. However, noisy is also the correct choice to be honest. The final goal is to have alpha2 separated into three vectors which produce 'smooth' curves. The values of alpha2, however, may not be changed (e.g. average etc...), because alpha2 values will be used for future calculations.

Comment: @user5489: Sanitizing your data manually is not an option? It seems those functions are all quadratic, so if there's really a need to do this automatically, you could do RANSAC to find the coefficients of the underlying polynomials and use those to partition the data points into the desired sets. (Which seems like a lot of work for just swapping some row-entries).

Comment: @user5489: A simpler approach would be to look for points with large second derivative, if swapping the values left to those points with one of the other functions makes the sum of the second derivatives smaller, then they are likely to be *entangled*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution using extrapolation via `polyfit`:

The idea is pretty simple: Iterate over all positions `i` and use `polyfit` to fit polynomials of degree `d` to the `d+1` values from `F(:,i-(d+1))` up to `F(:,i)`. Use those polynomials to extrapolate the function values `F(:,i+1)`. Then compute the permutation of the real values `F(:,i+1)` that fits those extrapolations best. This should work quite well, if there are only a few functions involved. There is certainly some room for improvement, but for your simple setting it should suffice.

```
function F = untangle(F, maxExtrapolationDegree)
%//   UNTANGLE(F) untangles the functions F(i,:) via extrapolation.
if nargin<2
    maxExtrapolationDegree = 4;
end
extrapolate = @(f) polyval(polyfit(1:length(f),f,length(f)-1),length(f)+1);
extrapolateAll = @(F) cellfun(extrapolate, num2cell(F,2));
fitCriterion = @(X,Y) norm(X(:)-Y(:),1);

nFuncs = size(F,1);
nPoints = size(F,2);
swaps = perms(1:nFuncs);
errorOfFit = zeros(1,size(swaps,1));
for i = 1:nPoints-1
    nextValues = extrapolateAll(F(:,max(1,i-(maxExtrapolationDegree+1)):i));
    for j = 1:size(swaps,1)
        errorOfFit(j) = fitCriterion(nextValues, F(swaps(j,:),i+1));
    end
    [~,j_bestSwap] = min(errorOfFit);
    F(:,i+1) = F(swaps(j_bestSwap,:),i+1);
end
```

### Initial solution: (not that pretty - Skip this part)

This is a similar solution that tries to minimize the sum of the derivatives up to some degree of the vector valued function `F = @(j) alpha2(:,j)`. It does so by stepping through the positions `i` and checks all possible permutations of the coordinates of `i` to get a minimal seminorm of the function `F(1:i)`.
(I'm actually wondering right now if there is any canonical mathematical way to define the seminorm so we get our expected results... I initially was going for the `H^1` and `H^2` seminorms, but they didn't quite work...)

```
function F = untangle(F)
nFuncs = size(F,1);
nPoints = size(F,2);
seminorm = @(x,i) sum(sum(abs(diff(x(:,1:i),1,2)))) + ...
                  sum(sum(abs(diff(x(:,1:i),2,2)))) + ...
                  sum(sum(abs(diff(x(:,1:i),3,2)))) + ...
                  sum(sum(abs(diff(x(:,1:i),4,2))));
doSwap = @(x,swap,i) [x(:,1:i-1), x(swap,i:end)];
swaps = perms(1:nFuncs);
normOfSwap = zeros(1,size(swaps,1));
for i = 2:nPoints
    for j = 1:size(swaps,1)
        normOfSwap(j) = seminorm(doSwap(F,swaps(j,:),i),i);
    end
    [~,j_bestSwap] = min(normOfSwap);
    F = doSwap(F,swaps(j_bestSwap,:),i);
end
```

### Usage:

The command `alpha2 = untangle(alpha2);` will untangle your functions: [image: Untangle]

It should even work for more complicated data, like these shuffled sine-waves:

```
nPoints = 100;
nFuncs = 5;
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, nPoints);
F = bsxfun(@(a,b) sin(a*b), (1:nFuncs).', t);
for i = 1:nPoints
    F(:,i) = F(randperm(nFuncs),i);
end
```

[image: Sinus]

**Remark:** I guess if you already know that your functions will be quadratic or some other special form, [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) would be a better idea for larger number of functions. This could also be useful if the functions are not given with the same x-value spacing.

Comment: @user5489: Glad to help. Where did you get this shuffled data anyway?

Comment: The alpha2 (the three vector of it) are the solution to the cubic formula. I used the approach discussed [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html) to obtain the three different solutions (eq. 54-56) . Unfortunately, the solutions are not necessary sorted. The root finder function in Matlab doesn't sort the solutions either (in many cases it was worse).